# Want to track the iOS installs if the user install from Google ADs instead of directly from app store.

Tags: ios

I am trying to track source of the App whether it is coming from Google Ads. If it is installed by clicking from Google Ads then I want to get the confirmation when a user registers.

I have followed http://mobileapptracking.com/docs/MAT-Tracking-Methods-For-Mobile-Apps.pdf but can't get any solution.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you could find the solution here: http://support.mobileapptracking.com/forums/20877789-Integrated-Publishers

It's a set of articles which describe how to add an app publisher (like Google Ads), to view the related statistics, etc.